# How to implement the teams app sso using the @microsoft/teams-js package in react.js

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

There is node example of how to implement
https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs
i want it implement in React.js , to my existing teams app build in react

i tried in the similar way but i stuck in getting the authtoken, there is the function in node to get the auth token but it shows , "The signature '(authTokenRequest?: AuthTokenRequest): void' of 'authentication.getAuthToken' is deprecated.",

for this code
`` ` ``

```
   function getClientSideToken() {
        console.log("getClientSideToken")

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

          

           authentication.getAuthToken({
           
                successCallback: (result) => {
                   
                    resolve(result);
                },
                failureCallback: function (error) {
                    reject("Error getting token: " + error);
                }
            });

        });

    }
```

Comment: The same issue is being tracked here -https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/1855. Please check Github thread for futher updates.